# Can I manually add recurring contributions?

Tags: civicontribute

Is there a way to add a recurring donation if it hasn't been processed through CiviCRM? We are migrating over to Civi and some people give us donations through a direct bank transfer on a monthly basis. It would be helpful to be able to record these to their record on an ongoing basis.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Offline Recurring Payment Extension](https://github.com/pradpnayak/uk.co.circleinteractive.offlinerecurring) can add recurring contributions in Civi.

Also [membership extras extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/membership-extras) provides the feature but also some additional features which your Organization may or may not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

We use the [CiviContribute Recur Extra extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicontribute-recur-extra) for this. See the [readme section here for details](https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.contributionrecur#provide-offline-recurring-dummy-processors-for-both-credit-card-and-acheft) on how to set this up.

Comment: Yes, the "offline recurring dummy processors" feature of this extension is exactly for this use-case. You would set it up so that the monthly contribution records are automatically generated within civicrm, either completed (and then you can edit the ones that didn't actually go through) or incomplete (and then you manually complete the ones that you confirm went through).